# Sending a binary data from file in POST request with netcat

Tags: php, post, netcat

Well, I learned netcat a bit.
I have a php script on my server.
I use `nc -v xx.xxx.xxx.xx 9292` and then `get http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/myscript.php`.I see output of my page. Now I need to send a binary data that I have from tcpdump in file. As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187438/curl-send-file-as-post-request): I should use it like this:

```
cat request | nc host port
```

But when I try

```
cat "/var/www/9292/123bytes" |nc xx.xxx.xxx.xx 9292
```

or

```
cat "/var/www/9292/123bytes" |nc -v xx.xxx.xxx.xx 9292
```

I receive following mistake:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2015 05:12:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Content-Length: 385
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Request header field is missing ':' separator.<br />
<pre>
</pre>
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at ... Port 9292</address>
</body></html>
```

Here is output of `cat "/var/www/9292/123bytes"`

```
POST /makeTemplate123.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Cctv-Search/1.0
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: localhost:8050
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2095

......JFIF.....`.`.....C......
......(.....1#%.(:3=<9387@H\N@DWE78PmQW_bghg>Mqypdx\egc...C......./../cB8Bcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc........p.."......................................6......................!..1.A."Qa2q...B....#4Ccr......................................bytes
----1429512044467boundary--
```

As far as I see there is `:` in all headers. Also I had an advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892435/netcat-running-sending-binary-data-to-php-script) to check apache version. As you can see it's older than 2.2.15. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm thinking the unescaped colon in the Host header is what its complaining about..